# Jhipster registry running

Tags: maven, heroku, jhipster

I have imported last version of jhipster Registry ,when tryied to deploy with maven and open localhost:8761 I get error message like the following image

[image]

After deploying gateway get empty page

[image]

Comment: What do you see in browser's console?

Comment: No thing  in console